# screenshot stack not working

Tags: desktop, screen-capture

For the past couple of weeks my screenshot stack has been buggy.
Whenever I take screenshots some of em end up in the right stack and some of them form a separate stack on the same desktop called images.
But when I right click on the desktop and uncheck 'use stacks' option and then again right click and check 'use stacks' it gets rearranged correctly, i.e, the images stack now disappears and all the screenshots are inside the screenshot stack.

Answer (score -1):

It was back to normal after clearing all the cache